# What's so special about Markov chain compared to independent probabilities?

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I don't get what's special about a Markov process compared to say calculate independent probabilities for multiple events. Is it about the fact that the Markov process can 're-visit' previous states? Thanks!

Comment: It has a "memory" where you can express the *conditional* probabilities between states.

Comment: You might start by asking yourself how to model the sequence of temperatures each day at noon at a given place? Is it reasonable to consider that the fact that the temperature today was $-20°C$ or $0°C$ or $+20°C$ has no bearing on tomorrow's temperature? If, as I hope, your answer is "No", then you are in effect throwing every independent model to the bin for this task... and Markov models are then the simplest option.